# SpriteKit: modify SKScene frame programmatically

Tags: sprite-kit, skscene, sklabelnode, skview

I want to modify the size of `SKScene` but I have figure out how to do it. I have figure out how change the size but it square taking the smallest size of the screen:

```
func makeScene() -> SKScene {
        let minimumDimension = min(view.frame.width, view.frame.height)
        let size = CGSize(width: minimumDimension, height: minimumDimension)
        let scene = SKScene(size: size)
        scene.backgroundColor = .white
        return scene
}
```

Any of you knows how can I modify SKScene size (frame) programmatically ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you want to modify your scene size?  That seems like odd behavior.

Answer (score 2):

To modify the GameScene screen size, you can set go to GameScene.swift, and set the values.

```
self.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
```

Over here I have set the GameScene size to be 100 X 100. You can also change these values in the GameScene.sks, but the value stated in the code would over write it.